# Parsing a JSON retrieved int32 into a core data class with swift

Tags: ios, json, core-data, swift

I have a Core Data class which is being populated via a JSON rest API call using Swift.

I can parse the dictionary without any problems for strings, but cannot parse the ID field which is an Int32.

My code is:

```
class Job: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var id: Int32
}


if let id = resultDict["JobID"] as? NSNumber {
    job.id = Int32(id) // THIS LINE IS CAUSING THE ERROR 
}
```

The error that I'm getting when trying to build is:  'Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments"

Comment: What do you mean "cannot parse"?  What does the original JSON look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Int32` doesn't have an initializer that takes an `NSNumber`. You can use the [`intValue` property of `NSNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSNumber/intValue) directly though; it returns an `Int32`:

```
job.id = id.intValue
```